# GetWindowText is returning nothing

Tags: vb.net, dllimport, hwnd, entry-point

In one of my project I have to get the title of foreground window so I called GetForegroundWindow() Entry Point form User32.dll for getting the windows Handle then I called GetWindowText() for the title everything goes error less but the output comes nothing, here is the code I am using in my VB.NET program.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr

End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Long) As Integer

End Function


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim hWnd As IntPtr
    hWnd = GetForegroundWindow()
    Dim title As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
    GetWindowText(hWnd, title, title.Capacity)
    Me.Text = title.ToString
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That is a VB6 declaration, an old VB version that started as a 16-bit dev tool.   You can always tell by seeing `Long` back.  It is `Integer` in VB.NET.  Get up-to-date declarations by visiting, say, the pinvoke.net web site.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution myself, It was the fault in the `hWnd` parameter as `Long` value for proper functioning of the program it has to be `IntPtr`. The new correct code looks something like this.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr

End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Long) As Integer

End Function


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim hWnd As IntPtr
    hWnd = GetForegroundWindow()
    Dim title As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
    GetWindowText(hWnd, title, title.Capacity)
    Me.Text = title.ToString


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: As pointed out in the comment, Long = Integer.  You missed the cch argument.  Use the web site.

Comment: The biggest mistake is the absence of error checking